# WordPress localhost site redirect to live site

Tags: wordpress, localhost, redirect

I have download the code and export the database from server and setup the site on my localhost also I have been changed the home and site URL in wp_options table I am able to login at `wp-admin` but when I am clicking on the home page it redirect me to live site.

If anyone know the issue please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your menu may contain custom link to your homepage. Check that under Appearance > Menus

Comment: I have checked there is no custom link

Comment: Is there any redirect code written in header.php file? Did you checked that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408274/switch-over-wordpress-site-server/38408306#38408306    check answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to replace database URL and directory path while downloading database from 1 provider to other. In your case, I suspect that you have downloaded database directly, without changing URL and directory path.

You need to re-download database. You can simply use "WP Migrate DB" plugin for this. You can find it [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/)

Let me know if you need further assistance...

Comment: But I am able to login at back-end in local host

Comment: You can login as this doesn't depend on database...

If you have not followed the steps I mentioned above than please follow it and let me know...

Comment: I have followed and other pages are open but only the home page redirect to live site

Comment: Can you try once by changing permalinks to "Plain" and again to "Original"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141946/discussion-between-israr-mansuri-and-wildprogrammers).

Comment: Replacing the URL form the database wp_options fixed the issue thanks

Answer (score 2):

open your wp-config.php file and add this

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/your_wordpress_folder' );  
define( 'WP_HOME',    'http://localhost/your_wordpress_folder' );
```

then save the file 
from admin set the permalinks defaults and resave it with %postname%

if not work recreate your htaccess file

Hope it will work for you

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. I changed the permalink type and reset MAMP. Before resetting MAMP, I changed the web server type from Nginx to Apache in MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update guid as well to for site url and admin url which is in wp_post table..

just run below query in your phpmyadmin

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://liveserver', 'http://localhost');

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I have already did this but still unable to see the front-end

Answer (score 0):

open your database via phpmyadmin then search %localhost% inside all tables.

Then change any localhost value inside your database.

Comment: can you share the site url?